# What analytic philosophy books on the meaning of life are there?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, meaning-of-life

Because almost every book on meaning of life is in continental philosophy or religious.

Comment: A lot hinges on how you define "analytic", because almost by definition the original project of analytic philosophy wouldn't be interested in the "meaning of life" as a topic of research.

Comment: Alain Badiou's Being and Event books. I have no idea what sort of logic he's up to here, but I thought I would mention his name.

Comment: To me, the search for an answer for the meaning of life in analytic philosophy has a lot in common with the search for the answer in monotheism. This is a search for the Father. Schopenhauer, Buddhism, may be seen as a dissolving of the problem of Will (attachment) in the great Mother.

Comment: So Schopenhauer simply liquidates the problem by liquidating the ego. With the analytic approach, the idea is "I know something" (it's usually trivial) and I can hide behind this wall and the Father will protect me.  There is nothing "wrong" with either choice, these are very human responses to anxiety, agnst, nihilism.

Comment: NB:  Now an existentialist (eg Sartre) may claim that both groups are in bad faith, and that they are both hiding, but we cannot fail to mention that Sartre himself liked to be mothered.

Comment: could try [this](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/meaning-in-life-9780199599318?cc=gb&lang=en&) definitely analytic